# NUnit isn't running Visual Studio 2010 code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, nunit

I'm trying to load a Visual Studio 2010 beta dll into the NUnit GUI.  I get a popup error.

> This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.  You may be attempting to load an assembly build with a later version of the CLR than the version under which NUnit is currently running.

How do I force an executable to run under .NET 4?

Comment: Is this question actually relates to VS 2010 or .NET 4 code? -- I am looking for a tool that allows me to run NUNIT tests on Visual Studio 2010, and this question was misleading.

Comment: @Nicolas - its referring to .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I've downloaded the NUnit 2.5 source and opened the VS2008 solution in the VS2010 beta. Once the conversion finished I opened all the projects and changed the target framework setting for all the projects to ".NET Framework 4.0". I then built the solution without any errors. I can now use the NUnit GUI app to run tests built for .NET 4.0. I've not done exhaustive testing of this build so there may be problems, but for my purposes it works fine.

Update: It is not necessary to rebuild NUnit. I discovered that if you add the following to the relevant NUnit config file you can run a test dll built for .NET 4.0.

Under <configuration> add:

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
</startup>
```

and under <runtime> add:

```
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
```

Comment: Ok, the configuration updates make it work, but I had to use version="v4.0.21006" for my requiredRuntime tag.

Comment: BTW, the default location of the config file is:
C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.3\bin\net-2.0\nunit.exe.config

Adding those options to the config worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me when using the consolerunner as well. 

I was running using the NUnit task for MSBuild Community Tasks project.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work with the latest Nunit + .net4 RTM. I added the suggested entries to nunit-console.exe.config but I get:

 System.ArgumentException: The net-4.0 framework is not available

Tried with the above versions + v4.0.30319
I'm running 2008 R2 x64

Comment: For the console runner, change the configs as mentioned, but using v4.0.30319 for the RTM version of .NET 4.0.  Also, run it with this command line argument: /framework=4.0.30319

Comment: I had luck using the command line option /framework:net-4.0.30319 instead of changing the config. This was helpful so I could control which applications used the 4.0 CLR and which did not.

Comment: +1 and updated the version no in the answer to the RTM version of .NET 4.0 as that is what people will be looking for now.

Comment: +1 Another data point: I made the two changes in the config file and now I can run .NET 4 tests in NUnit. :)

Comment: +1 Surprisingly, pelazem's situation didn't work in one instance, but this fixed the GUI part of NUnit.

Answer (score 25):

With .NET 4 being released, I used

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
```

in the NUnit 2.5.4 exe.config instead of requiredRuntime, and the loadFromRemoteResources tag as shown above and all worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You don't have to modify any file

just open this file and everything will work just fine

**C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.10\bin\net-2.0\nunit-x86.exe**

Comment: Thank you - solved my case. Have to use x86 version of nunit for unit tests compiled x86. CLR version warnings were a red-herring. Using nunit 2.5.10.

Comment: Same here, somehow has to use x86 version

Answer (score 12):

In [NUnit 2.5.5](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5.5) you can specify in the command line the option **/framework=net-4.0** and it is compatible with the new assemblies generated with the release of the latest VS2010.

Comment: I have never been able to get this to work.  I have seen people use /framework:net-4.0.30319 and all sorts of other variations.  Would be nice if they included the actual options on the site docs.

Comment: @Jason It appears that this only works on the console version. The GUI version doesn't have this option.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this works starting from version 2.5.5! I had NUnit throwing ArgumentExceptions and NullReferenceExceptions on one of my machines, and it turned out that it was because of version 2.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution worked great for getting NUnit to run. Unfortunately, when I then got to my code coverage step, NCover started giving me:

> Profiled process terminated. Profiler
>   connection not established.

The best solution I found to this was to just use the "-x86" version of NUnit with NCover:

> NCover.Console.exe
>   nunit-console-x86.exe --additional params--

Works now.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was experiencing the same issue, your fix solved it!

Answer (score 2):

To find your .net 4 version from the Visual [C# 2010 Express, or which ever] go to the Visual application's "About" under the menu's Help item. It should show up as the version under the Microsoft .NET Framework line on the top right hand side of the window.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the very same error message while running NUnit 2.4.8. As I had not upgraded in some time I installed the current NUnit (v2.5.9) and found that it now supports VS2010 assemblies. So if you have newly encountered this error *check your NUnit version*: as of December 2010 (or so) the **only** thing you need to do is upgrade NUnit.

Comment: i am running NUnit 2.5.9 downloaded on 15/03/2011 and this problem just wont go away for me.  Even if i try the proposed solution

Answer (score 1):

As of NUnit 2.5.10 you can enable visual studio support in the GUI runner:

> Tools-> Settings-> IDE Support

After that I was able to successfully attach to the nunit-agent.exe process which runs your assembly in a .NET 4.0 app domain

Answer (score 0):

If you experience this issue after upgrading to nunit 2.5.5 then you will need to upgrade nant to the latest version for me it was .91 alpha.

Answer (score 0):

I [found](http://www.csharpblog.co.cc/2011/05/integrate-nunit-with-visual-studio.html) usefull to start from NUnit Application [Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b8a7a8fa-9f5a-4b9b-8e8b-8839a4364f26). It support VS C# Express, allows debugging tests and contains precompiled NUnit for .NET 4.0. Thank to author new test project gets ready with one click.