# NUnit in TFS 2008 and .NET 4.0

Tags: nunit, .net-4.0

Is there a way to set /framework:net-4.0 in nunit-console.exe.config [like in GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930438/nunit-isnt-running-vs10-code)? Or any other way to run NUnit tests with [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930438/nunit-isnt-running-vs10-code) was applicable to NUnit GUI only, appearently it is applicable to [any .NET application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx). So to answer my own question, all you have to do is 
add `<startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>` to nunit-console.exe.config and you don't have to specify it as a command argument.