# NUnit.Runners via Nuget on Visual Studio 2012 express doesn't work

Tags: .net, nunit, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm trying to set up simple NUnit project in Visual Studio 2012 Express using NuGet manager. 
From PROJECT-> Manage NuGet Packages I installed NUnit (framework) and wanted add NUnit.Runner but during installation I'm receiving:

```
'NUnit.Runners 2.6.2' already installed.
```

Ok, but when I go to the TOOLS->Library Package Manager->Manage nuGet Packages for Solution
 both NUnit (framework) and NUnit.Runners are displayed as installed.

I can use NUnit framework in the code but when I'm trying to run tests the old 'Test Explorer' stays and doesn't show anything. Tests are not invoked neither.

Am I missing something in VS2012 or NUnit configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I've found out Visual Studio Express does not support project extensions (forbidden and disabled by Microsoft). So it seems there's no option to use NUnit without some workarounds. So far I installed full version and there NUnit runner works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the approach sombody mentioned in the comments of this [blog post](http://stewartr.blogspot.de/2006/09/debugging-nunit-in-visual-studio.html):

1. Add a reference to nunit-console-runner in your test assembly.
2. In your test assembly, make a class with the following one liner (*see below*)
3. Open your test assembly's properties. For example, right-click on the assembly and select Properties.

   1. On the Application tab, select Output Type: Windows Application; and Startup Object: NUNitConolseRunner (the file above).
   2. On the Debug tab, enter the .csproj file name in Command Line Arguments; and browse to the folder of the .csproj file in Working Directory.
4. Save everything, set a breakpoint and run using F5 or the green arrow button.

Code:

```
using System;
namespace MotorExampleTests
{     
    // Written by blokeley
   class NUnitConsoleRunner
   {

     [STAThread]
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(args);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach but couldn't get it to work.  So I figured out a way to make it work. What I did instead was create a separate console project and then run my tests from the Main method by running the following line:   `NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(new string[] {@"C:\myprograms\mysolution\MyProject.Test\bin\Debug\MyProject.Test.dll" });`

Comment: Also this allows me to keep my tests as a dll instead of an exe as the post above suggests.

Comment: Instead of hardcoded paths you can get the path via `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)`

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the built in testrunner in VS2012 and add the nunit testadapter via the extension manager?