# What steps should I take to troubleshoot a testdriven.net installation?

Tags: nunit, testdriven.net

I'm trying to get up and running with nUnit, which has been pretty painful so far. I have successfully installed and added a reference to the nUnit framework, and I've successfully created a simple test--but get this error when I try to use the nUnit GUI:
[C# .NET 4.0 Testing Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898087/c-sharp-net-4-0-testing-framework)

On the advice of that post, I'm now trying to run nUnit from inside VS2010 with testdriven.net. I successfully installed testdriven.net, but when I re-start visual studio, I simply don't see the context menus described in the testdriven.net [quickstart](http://www.testdriven.net/quickstart.aspx). How do I know if testdriven.net even installed correctly? What can I do to get up set up with testdriven.net or nUnit?

Comment: if you wanna check if it's installed, go to: Tools->Add in Manager, you should see it listed there

Comment: it's not there. thanks for that tip. what should i do next?

Comment: Thanks again Bassam. I just tried that and it is still not coming up in the add in manager. any ideas? maybe try re-installing with an admin account? I do see a thing called "create unit tests" in the context menu, but it does not look anything like the screenshots for the test driven context menu on the quickstart (linked above). meaning: I'm not sure if testdriven added the "create unit tests" in the context menu, but test driven is not showing up in the add-in manager and does not look like their screenshots, so it seems like the install still failed

Comment: yeah.. as long as it's not in the add in manager, you won't see any context menus... here is all I can think of: make sure you download RTM not the beta version, right click and unblock the zip file, install as admin.. let me know if any of that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna check if it's installed, go to: Tools->Add in Manager, you should see it listed there.

If it's not there, then it is not installed, try the following:

1. try uninstalling from control panel 'TestDriven.Net 3.0 Personal', restart, then install again while visual studio is closed
2. make sure you download the **RTM** not the **beta** version, right click and **unblock** the zip file, install as **admin**.