# NUnit 2.5.9 Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, nunit, nunit-2.5.9

Good morning, afternoon, or night,

I am trying to use NUnit 2.5.9 to run some unit tests contained in an assembly built with Visual Studio 2010 which targets .NET 2.0. However, I keep getting a `System.BadImageFormatException` exception everytime... I tried the workarounds described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930438/nunit-isnt-running-visual-studio-2010-code), but to no avail. I have also downloaded the source code and compiled it under Visual Studio 2010 targeting .NET 2.0, but the exception keeps popping up... What is going wrong here?

```
System.BadImageFormatException...

Server stack trace: 
   em System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   em System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   em System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   em NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   em NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   em NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   em NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   em NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   em NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   em NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   em NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   em System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   em System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   em System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   em System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   em NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   em NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   em NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen similar errors trying to test x86 assemblies on a 64-bit system.

You may need to run nunit-x86.exe instead of nunit.exe.