# BadImageFormatException while using nUnit for COM object wrapper test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, com, nunit

I'm going to refactor a piece of overcomplicated code and I want to do it in a safe manner. In order to do it I have written an unit test. But I can't use the test because it always fails with a **BadImageFormatException**:

> Could not load file or assembly 'XXX, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ZZZ' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

The XXX assembly is a **proxy-assembly of the COM object**. It is added as a refence to the project containing the test.

Currently I use the **nUnit 2.5.7**.

Couldn't anyone point me how can I solve the problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that your application is running under .NET 4.0, and NUnit - under .NET 2.0

See this: [NUnit isn't running Visual Studio 2010 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930438/nunit-isnt-running-visual-studio-2010-code)

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I just didn't see that. Thanks. I'll try to search how can I change the NUnit's runtime.