# nunit-console tests produces different result from different locations

Tags: .net-4.0, nunit-console

I have got nunit-console.exe in 2 locations on my machine. First is where I installed it (c:\program files (x86)\nunit 2.5.10) and second is where I have copied it into (d:\tests\nunit). I am required to work with the copied version.

I am trying to run a test from a test assembly and I get strange results. When I try to invoke the installed version, the test runs fine. But, when I try to invoke the copied version, the tests dont run. The copied version was initally throwing the *NUnit components for version 4.0.30319 of the CLR are not installed* error and I followed the solution for  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930438/nunit-isnt-running-visual-studio-2010-code) question to fix it. But, now the tests (which include BizUnit 2010 maps and schemas) fail with an error which I am unable to fix.

The strange this is, if I invoke the installed version, all runs smooth. I am not required to do any config changes and tests pass ok.

I tried to use the `/domain=None` option of nunit-console.exe, the tests pass. But, I dont want to use it.

Please can someone help? What am I missing?

I am running on Win 2008R2 with .NET version 4 and NUnit version 2.5.10

Thanks

Comment: I just noted that when I run the *installed* version, i can see 2 processes running as `nunit-agent.exe` and `nunit-console.exe`. But when I run the *copied* version, I see onl the `nunit-console.exe` process running.

Comment: I figured out the answer myself!!! There was an issue in the way we had copied the nunit files. I corrected those and alls well now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. In my case it was because the path where I had copied nunit included a # letter. I renamed the folder and it worked flawlessly.

I got the answer from here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/bc73uuP-Lbw