# How to debug Nunit test with VS 2010 sp1?

Tags: nunit

```
namespace MoqSample.Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class GivenCustomerServiceTest
    {
        private ICustomerService customerService;
        private CustomerModel customer;
        // Defining the mock object.
        private Mock<ICustomerRepository> mockCustomerRepository;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            //Creating the mock object.
            mockCustomerRepository = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
            customerService = new CustomerService(mockCustomerRepository.Object);
        }

        [Test]
        public void GetCustomerByIdTest()
        {
            customer = new CustomerModel { Id = 1, Name = "TEST-CUSTOMER", Address = "abc" };
            mockCustomerRepository.Setup(customerRepository => customerRepository.GetCustomerById(1)).Returns(customer);

            var customerReturned = customerService.GetCustomerById(1);

            //Verifying values.
            Assert.AreEqual(customer.Id, customerReturned.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(customer.Name, customerReturned.Name);
            Assert.AreEqual(customer.Address, customerReturned.Address);
        }
    }
}
```

When I am trying to debug the code in aforementioned class , it's not hitting the break point.
I.e I am unable to debug the code.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930438/nunit-isnt-running-visual-studio-2010-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html)** or **[TestDriven](http://testdriven.net/quickstart.aspx)** test runners should allow you to debug through your unit tests.

Comment: Thank you.
Apologies for replying late, as I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: Install Nuget Package Test Drive Test Runner.